# Correct approach to create instance in ES6 (protractor page objects)

Tags: javascript, protractor, ecmascript-6

just started to learn ES6 and I want to test page by using Protractor. First I want to create base web element class and other elements on page will be inherited from base class.

Protractor has selectors which you can use to select elements and operate with them, for example click:

```
var button = element(by.css('.button'));
button.click();
```

So basically I want to create something like this:

```
class BaseElement {
  constructor(selector){
    this._element = element(selector);
  }
var button = new BaseElement(by.css('.button));
button.click();
```

For some reason it doesn't work :

```
button.click();//button is an instance of base class BaseElement
```

it returns that click is not a function.

I can add some method "click" to class, or "get" method, like in example below, but I need to know maybe I've missed some basic principles and doing it completely wrong. In Protractor there are a lot of native, built in functions for elements and I don't want to write methods for all of them in the base class.

```
class BaseElement {
      constructor(selector){
         this._element = element(selector);
    }
    get element() {
        return this._element;
    }
}
var button = new BaseElement(by.css('.button));
button.element.click()//DON'T WANT TO USE THIS, LOOKING FOR USE of button.click() WITHOUT CREATING ANY METHODS IN CLASS IF POSSIBLE
```

Comment: Does your `BaseElement` class have any own methods of itself at all? I mean, what do you need it for?

Comment: If Protractor would have exposed `ElementFinder` as a class it would have been possible I think (with `extends`), but as it is not written like that, I don't think there is another way then to redefine each method on `BaseElement`.

Comment: @Bergi I want to use base class in feature to decorate all child elements with some custom logic if I've correctly understand your question

Comment: So you want to write a mixin/decorator function, not a `class`?

Comment: @Bergi In few words I want to use native protractor methods like click() on all instances of base element

Comment: You have: var button = new BaseElement(by.css('.button));

Close the single quote: 

var button = new BaseElement(by.css('.button'));

Comment: @KCaradonna Thanks for pointing, just edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Protractor would have exposed `ElementFinder` as a class you would probably have been able to achieve what you want with this syntax:

```
class BaseElement extends ElementFinder {
    constructor(selector){
        super(selector);
        // ...
    }
    // ... 
}
```

But as Protractor is not written with classes, this is not working.

Alternatively, you could define `BaseElement` as a simple function which extends a given element (an `ElementFinder` instance) with some of your own custom behaviour:

```
function makeBaseElement(selector) {
    // add some properties to the element for the given selector and return it:
    return Object.defineProperties(element(selector), {
        "property1": {
            value: true,
            writable: true
        },
        "property2": {
            value: "Hello",
            writable: false
        }
        // etc.
    });
}

var button = makeBaseElement(by.css('.button));
button.click();
```

Of course, this is not ES6, nor is `button` of the class `BaseElement`, but for the rest it combines the element behaviour with any additional properties.

You could also have a look at the possibility to create a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which would detect whether the get/set of a property should be forwarded to `_element` instead of the main `BaseElement` object.